# Hash info of an torrent

Tags: php, hash, bittorrent

I was talking to an recent developer for my website and he suggested that I store the hash info of a torrent into a database, so I have some questions about `hash_info` of an torrent.

1. What will storing the hash info of an torrent accomplish in terms of RAM and CPU usage?
2. When an torrent is created; is the hash info actually stored in the torrent file?

He has told me that by storing the hash info into a database then calling it again as an variable that it will reduce the time needed to create the torrent but I am unsure of what and how this will happen.

Comment: So are you generating customised torrents for different users accessing the same swarm? Certainly you would only generate the hash once, when you are initially creating the swarm - if you generated the hash every time a torrent file was given to a new peer a) it will eat system resources and b) if your local copy of the file (the one you are hashing) becomes corrupt, the hash will be wrong and the error will propagate so swarm's data will become corrupted, which sort of negates one of the main purposes of the hash.

Comment: no, the torrent will be created once with an cron job then the same torrent will be served for download to all the users

Comment: FYI, my service will be an automated torrent creation given an file upload or an http url, I just wanted to check my understanding; because I thought the only reason that the hash will be stored was to check against dupe files

Comment: Well in that case all you need to do is hash the payload data and create a valid torrent file, of which the hash is an integral part. Are you hashing the pieces or using the [Merkle hash](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0030.html) extension (which you probably should)? How are you collecting the tracker information?

Comment: @DaveRandom My main concern is not overloading my server as I am still on shared; currently it is hashing the pieces, tracker info is preset;

Comment: Ohhh I've just clicked with what you are doing. So because this is a public site, there is a possibility that someone my submit the same file? With direct file uploads there's not much you can do about this as you can't rely on the file name supplied by the client, it would be impossible to determine whether you have a dupe until you hash file. But you *could* stored a list of URL->hash relationships in a DB, so if someone submits a duplicate URL you know what the hash is - although content served by that URL may change over time as well (casing point: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)

Comment: To be honest I don't know what to recommend for the best here, I would say maybe only cache hashes generated for URLs that a) don't have a query string portion and b) send headers that permit caching. Then when you do get a dupe, request the file with an `If-Modified-Since:` header, and serve the stored hash if you get a 304, generate a new hash otherwise.